# Can't update title in desktop version of word

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins

I have an Office Addin and am trying to update the title of the document on desktop. i have tried 2 diffrent ways and none of them works on hte desktop. It works fine on word online but not on the desktop.

```
Word.run(async (context) => {

   var newTitle = document.getElementById("inputTitle") as HTMLInputElement;
   console.log(newTitle.value);
   context.document.properties.title = newTitle.value;

   });
```

This code works online but not on the desktop. I have also tried doing doing it in this way.

```
Office.context.document.customXmlParts.getByNamespaceAsync("http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/metadata/core-properties", 
function (resultCore) {

   var xmlPart = resultCore.value[0];
   xmlPart.getNodesAsync('*/*', function (nodeResult) {

      for (var i = 0; i < nodeResult.value.length; i++) {

       var node = nodeResult.value[i];
       console.log("BaseName: ")
       console.log(node.baseName);

           if (node.baseName === "title") {

              var newTitle = document.getElementById("inputTitle") as HTMLInputElement;
              console.log("title that you entered: " + newTitle.value);
              console.log(node);

              node.setNodeValueAsync(newTitle.value, { asyncContext: "StateNormal" }, function (data) { });

       }

     }

   });
});
```

Does anyone know why it doesn't work or have some other solution to my problem?

Comment: Could you please be more specific by what you mean with "title"? Where do you see this information change on-line / where do you expect to see it change on the desktop?

Comment: The Title of the word document. I have a document library on my sharepoint site. In my list i have made a word document, I then open it and can change the title using both my code examples. But if i want to edit the title of the document in desktop. none of my code works. hope this helps a little bit.

Comment: Tim, can you please indicate your build number? thanks!

Comment: @JuanBalmori I have 16.0.4266.1001. i was also thinking that my version of Words desktop is to old? Could that be my problem?

Comment: @TimHaka yes i think that's potentially the problem. i strongly recommend you to update and let us know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me, including on desktop. Note that you have to `await` the `Word.run`. Also, you have to load the title and then sync to make sure you have changed the title on the actual document and not merely in the proxy object in your task pane code.

```
await Word.run(async (context) => {
    var newTitle = document.getElementById("inputTitle") as HTMLInputElement;
    console.log(newTitle.value);
    context.document.properties.title = newTitle.value;
    const myProperties = context.document.properties.load("title");
    await context.sync();
    console.log(myProperties.title);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i get this error when i run your code.
Unhandled promise rejection TypeError: Unable to set property 'title' of undefined or null reference. I just answered Juan that my Build number of office word is 16.0.4266.1001 is this why it dosent work?